# How to change structure of subversion repository after a migration?

Tags: svn, migration, version, structure, pvcs

I am a newbie to both Subversion and PVCS VM
I currently migrated my project from PVCS VM to Subversion
And I now have this structure 
I got the project and in my project i got my components
inside each components I have trunk, branches and tags.

We are trying to change the structure to have 
the project and then I got my components and each component would only have branches and tags.

The branches would have to only contain the last version of each major version.

Also how to I only get a certain version? I need to take version 5.1.2 until 5.2.0
Nothing before 5.1.2 and nothing after 5.2.0

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) has good information. You might want to read up on [Branch Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.maint.html) and [Planning Your Repository Organization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout)

Answer (score 0):

Use [svn move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html) to restructure your repository and then [svn copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re07.html) to create your branches.